# Creating a multiple choice Google Form by using random images from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, forms, google-forms

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column with file paths for images. I need to create a google form that randomly picks three images every time someone opens it and display multiple choices under each. Is there a way to do this without having to use Apps Scripts?